# First record by month & by year

Tags: postgresql

I have a Rails application with 20+ years of data.

I'm struggling to create two SQLs:

1. Fetch the first record of each year (based on filters)
2. Fetch the first record of each month (based on filters)

I made a DBFiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wjQqrrpaJeiYG8zkExbaos/0

For the first query (yearly), the result should be:

```
a     | b_id  | created_at
74780 | 82373 | 2020-01-02 01:34:33 +0000
15670 | 16639 | 2019-02-24 14:33:56 +0000
14586 | 87594 | 2018-01-06 09:14:31 +0000
```

I can fetch the years and months using `date_part('year', created_at)` and `date_part('month', created_at)`, but didn't find a way to "glue" them with `min(created_at)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [window function OVER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/tutorial-window.html):

```
with grouped as(
       select *, min(created_at)  over(partition by  date_trunc('year', created_at)) 
       from z  order by date_trunc('year', created_at) desc
     )
select a, b_id, created_at from grouped where min = created_at
```

For the first record by month you can use the same approach by replacing all `date_trunc('year', created_at)` with `date_trunc('month', created_at)`